# I'm trying to put an image for a player on an HTML5 canvas in a .io game

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, canvas

I'm trying to make an online multiplayer .io game with HTML5 canvas and node.js I need to put the player on the canvas but when I try to add an image to the canvas like normal nothing shows up I suspect that this has to do with the file being sent from a server. Does anyone know how can do this? the file is called pp.png (stands for prism player) and it is in a folder called img whereas the script is in a folder called js .

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>rainboz.io</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href='client/styles/main.css' type="text/css">
        <div id="canvo-container"> <!-- Canvas container outside of container div -->
            <canvas id='canvo'></canvas> 
         
        </div>
        <script src='client/js/script.js'></script>
        <script src='https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--title-->
        <div id="container">
        <!--changelog-->
        <h2 id='changeot'>Changelog</h2>
        <h2 id="changein">Changelog</h2>

        <!--last upadated-->
        <h2 id='lastupot'>Last Updated: June 22, 2020</h2>
        <h2 id="lastupin">Last Updated: June 22, 2020</h2>
        
        <!--upadates-->
        <p id='toppot'>
            - I just created this changelog,<br/>
            this is where chages will go whenever I make them but <br/>
            I dont have any yet.

        </p>
        <p id='toppin'>
            - I just created this changelog,<br/>
            this is where chages will go whenever I make them but <br/>
            I dont have any yet.

        </p>

        <!--updates 2-->

        <p id='midpot'>
            - I barely even know how to code at all,<br/>
            so I'm kinda just winging it for now <br/>
            I'll just look up how to do stuff as I go.

        </p>

        <p id='midpin'>
            - I barely even know how to code at all,<br/>
            so I'm kinda just winging it for now <br/>
            I'll just look up how to do stuff as I go.
        </p>

        <h2 id="versionnumot">Version Number: 01.03.02</h2> 
        <h2 id='versionnumin'>Version Number: 01.03.02</h2>

        <h2 id='cinfoot'>Contact | About</h2>
        <h2 id='cinfoin'>Contact | About</h2>

        <!--nickname and play button-->

        <div class='ctr'>
          <h1 id='outer'>rainboz.io</h1>
          <h1 id='inner'>rainboz.io</h1>
        </div>
        
        
        <div>
         
            <label id='spawnif'>this is the story of...</label>
            <label id='spawnifin'>this is the story of...</label>
            <input type='text' spellcheck='false' maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" id='nickname' placeholder="Nickname">
            <button id='playbtnot' onclick="myFunction()">Play</button>
            <button id='playbtnin' onclick="myFunction()">Play</button>
          
        </div>

       <form>
            <button id='rbtn'></button>
            <button id='dbtn'></button>
            <button id='ibtn'></button>
            <button id='tbtn'></button>
        </form>

            <button id='mgbtnot'>More Games</button>
            <button id='mgbtnin'>More Games</button>
            
         
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(trianglebg.png);
    background-size: 475px;
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  transition: 0.6s;
  width: 100vw;
}

#canvo-container {
 display: none;
}

#canvo {

}



@font-face {
    font-family: 'coconbold';
    src: url(Cocon-Bold-Font.otf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'coconregular';
    src: url(cocon-regular.otf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'coconlight';
    src: url(cocon-light.ttf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}

#outer {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 7rem;
  font-family: coconbold;
  font-weight: 100;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 20px black;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#inner {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: coconbold;
  font-weight: 100;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 7rem;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 40, 40, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 121, 4, 1) 27%, rgba(252, 241, 73, 1) 40%, rgba(82, 252, 73, 1) 50%, rgba(73, 197, 252, 1) 60%, rgba(106, 53, 255, 1) 73%, rgba(150, 0, 214, 1) 85%);
  background-size: 200%;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  animation: anim 4s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    background-position: 0%;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
}

#nickname {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 10px 0 9px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 30%;
  height: 8%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 1px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  caret-color: grey;
  animation-name: float-up-3;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

#spawnif {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  top: 36%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  color: black;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 6px black;
  animation-name: float-up-2;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

#spawnifin {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  top: 36%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
      animation-name: float-up-2;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

#playbtnin {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  width: 215px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  color: white;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  outline: none;
      animation-name: float-up-1;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

#playbtnot {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  width: 215px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(180, 179, 255);
  border-color: rgb(110, 107, 255);
  background-size: 500px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  outline: none;
    animation-name: float-up-1;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 6px black;
}

#playbtn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(161, 171, 255);
  border-color: rgb(103, 101, 255);
}

.ctr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 50%;
  animation-name: float-in;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes float-in {
  from {
    top: -50%;
  }
  to {
    top: 15%;
  }
}

@keyframes float-up-1 {
  from {
    top: 150%;
  }
  to {
    top: 50%;
  }
}

@keyframes float-up-2 {
  from {
    top: 140%;
  }
  to {
    top: 36%;
  }
}

@keyframes float-up-3 {
  from {
    top: 150%;
  }
  to {
    top: 40%;
  }
}

  #changeot {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 7%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 33px;
    font-family: coconbold;
    color: black;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 5px black;   
  }

  #changein {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 7%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 33px;
    font-family: coconbold;
    color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;   
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;  
  }

  #lastupin {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 48px;
    left: 9.5%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;   
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;  
  }

  #lastupot {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 48px;
    left: 9.5%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: black;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 5px black;   
  }
  
  #toppin {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 90px;
    left: 13%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;   
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;  
  }

  #toppot {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 90px;
    left: 13%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: black;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 4px black;   
  }

  #midpin {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 150px;
    left: 9.5%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;   
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;  
  }

  #midpot {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-radius: 130px;
    top: 150px;
    left: 9.5%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: black;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 4px black;   
  }
  
  #versionnumin {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 635px;
    left: 11.25%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;   
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;  
  }

  #versionnumot {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 635px;
    left: 11.25%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: black;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 5px black;   
  }

    #rbtn {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 600px;
    left: 1150px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: coconbold;
    color:white;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    background-color: rgb(253, 135, 106);
    border-color: rgb(255, 31, 2);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    outline: none;
  }

  #dbtn {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 600px;
    left: 1210px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: coconbold;
    color:white;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    background-color: rgb(189, 204, 255);
    border-color: rgb(109, 112, 255);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    outline: none;
  }

  #ibtn {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 600px;
    left: 1270px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: coconbold;
    color:white;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    background-color: rgb(165, 117, 255);
    border-color: rgb(120, 2, 255);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    outline: none;
  }

  
  #tbtn {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 600px;
    left: 1330px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: coconbold;
    color:white;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    background-color: rgb(148, 207, 255);
    border-color: rgb(0, 110, 255);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    outline: none;
  }

  #cinfoin {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 12px;
    right: -6%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;   
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;  
  }

  #cinfoot {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 90px;
    top: 12px;
    right: -6%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: coconregular;
    color: black;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 5px black;   
  }

  #mgbtnot {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 7px;
    left: 1095px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: coconbold;
    color:white;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    background-color: rgb(159, 255, 151);
    border-color: rgb(61, 167, 57);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 4px black;   
  }

  #mgbtnin {
    box-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 7px;
    left: 1095px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: coconbold;
    color:white;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color:transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    outline: none;
  }
```

My Server (node.js)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
    
});
app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client/'
));

serv.listen(2000);
console.log('Server started.');
```

My Script (the game)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

console.log(canvas);



var image = new Image();
image.src = 'client/img/pp.png';

ctx.drawImage(image, 100, 100, 50, 50);

ctx.fillRect(200, 200, 200, 200);

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('container').style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(func2, 650) 

}

function func2() {
        document.getElementById('canvo-container').style.display = "block";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are defining the variable "canvas":

`var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');`
`var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');`

twice first with the ID and the with no element note that the second time you're putting `document.querySelector('canvas');` here you will need to specify what type of tag you meant, by the other hand, there is no Id called "canvas" instead you have `<canvas id='canvo'></canvas>` , with a wrong name.

Comment: I originally did that when I was trying to fix a problem that I had beforehand that I fixed by moving the canvas tag. I turned it back to canvas and it still didn't work, am I supposed to but only one define the canvas once?

Comment: yes, you might want to do `<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>` and then select the id like this: `document.querySelector('#canvas')` not the # in front of the tag in the selector meaning that it is an id.

Comment: Redefining variables defined  with `var` is allowed (even in strict mode). Also the second query will return the canvas as it is a tag name query. The problem with the OPs code is not waiting for the image to load.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the image is not showing is because it has not loaded.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'client/img/pp.png';     // starts to load the image

ctx.drawImage(image, 100, 100, 50, 50);  // May or may not have loaded at this point
                                         // If not loaded nothing is drawn
```

To ensure that the image has loaded you should use the `onload` event by assigning a function to it.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'client/img/pp.png';     // starts to load the image
image.onload = () => {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 100, 100, 50, 50); // image has loaded and can be drawn
}
```

or better to use `addEventListener` and listen for the `load` event

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'client/img/pp.png';     // starts to load the image
image.addEventListener("load", () => {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 100, 100, 50, 50); // image has loaded and can be drawn
}, {once: true})
```

There is also the `error` event that will fire if there are problems getting the image. This will allow for graceful failure (maybe retry) of the app rather than just not working.

Comment: when I do either of these it doesn't work, I was fiddling with the forward and back arrows and the refresh page button, I found that eventually, the image showed up when I refreshed the page. I don't know why this happens.

Comment: I messed around with some stuff and it worked! thanks for the help I really appreciate.

Comment: @Saint when you load the image and it is in the cache then the load time is so short that its loaded before your code has got to the next line. This is a very short time (less than fractions of a millisecond) so any tiny change in how busy the device is can make it seam to work and not, randomly. Using the `load` event guarantees that it has loaded before you try to draw it. You can also check `Image.complete` property which will be `true` if loading process is complete BUT BE CAREFUL loading errors also complete the loading process and `ctx.draw` will throw if you try and draw that.